# gdb fails to launch in eclipse oxygen

Tags: c++, gdb, mingw, eclipse-oxygen

I downloaded the latest version of the C++ ide from eclipse called oxygen. I am trying to do a basic debug test with an application on windows 10 but get this error message:

```
Error in final launch sequence
Failed to execute MI command:
-file-exec-and-symbols C:/Users/Owner/eclipse-workspace/Hello/Debug/Hello.exe
Error message from debugger back end:
"C:/Users/Owner/eclipse-workspace/Hello/Debug/Hello.exe": not in executable format: File format not recognized
"C:/Users/Owner/eclipse-workspace/Hello/Debug/Hello.exe": not in executable format: File format not recognized
```

I added the path to the gdb executable in the mingw folder but I am still getting that error message.

Comment: "`Hellow.exe` not in executable format" -- Have you tried executing the program outside of Eclipse?  Were there any errors when building?

Comment: @ Thomas Matthews when I try gdb hello.exe it says that gdb isnt recognized. I added it to the path though. There were no errors in compilation of the program.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Well I managed to pull up the gdb in the command window but still getting the same error in the ide.

Comment: Have you tried executing the program without `gdb`?  Were there any errors when *building* the program?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews No errors when building.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Well, shoot. Dumb mistake on my part. I guess trying to run Mingw gdb 32 bit with 64 bit eclipse doesnt work. Should have guessed that right away. It also makes more sense when I look at what was in the includes file for the 64 bit version of eclipse project folder. It was the mingw for the anaconda installation.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Yep, got the 64 bit and fixed it. Although I have no idea why the anaconda mingw installation is in the includes folder. That makes no sense to me.